# Does Evasion work on Prismatic Wall/Sphere?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, rogue

Under [Prismatic Wall](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/p/prismatic-wall), the first 3 layers all have a reflex for half save.

[Evasion](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/rogue#TOC-Evasion-Ex-)

> At 2nd level and higher, a rogue can avoid even magical and unusual attacks with great agility. If she makes a successful Reflex saving throw against an attack that normally deals half damage on a successful save, she instead takes no damage.

Comment: What about the *wall*'s effect makes you think evasion would *not* work?

Comment: I need it to be specifically answered by a 3rd party so that if my GM ever challenges it, its not my reading, but what others have agreed upon.

Answer (score 5):

Evasion normally applies to *anything* with a Reflex save for half damage, so yes, it should work. Won't do you a lot of good, though, because the last layer is going to disintegrate you anyway.

Comment: Wrong, characters are not objects (unless their dead), they get plane shifted if they fail the will save. Once that last part is corrected THEN I will accept this as an answer.

Comment: Well hey, if you want to be pedantic about it, you'll be poisoned, petrified, driven mad, and THEN sent to another plane. You're right that it's not a disintegrate effect, though.